# Can't access camera PhoneGap 3.3

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, camera

## The Problem

I'm attempting to build my first PhoneGap app for iOS. I am using version 3.3.x.
For whatever reason, I can't seem to get the Camera feature to work on my iPhone 5S (haven't tested any other devices).

### What I've tried

- I've installed the `Camera Plugin`
- I've added the feature to the `config.xml` file on the `platform/ios/www` level.
- I've tried using [PhoneGap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) examples.
- I've tried using [other online examples](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap-from-scratch-camera-api-app-exporting--mobile-9519).
- I've tried buying the PhoneGap 3 book and going step-by-step through their method.

None of that seems to matter

### What works

- I've used a `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`, **this works**, but it's not really what I'm looking for. I'm trying to actually access the `Camera API`.
- `Geolocation plugin` I've tried and it works fine.
- Accessing external API's I have gotten to work.

### What also doesn't work

- `Contacts Plugin` also doesn't seem to be working with the examples on the PhoneGap Docs.

### Possible Clues

- I am running / building the app from within Xcode. I've also tried building using the `Command-Line Tool` but I'm not sure how to run it on my iPhone once it's been built through CLT. I don't know if this matters or not.
- There seems to be a "lag" in launch time when I include **any** scripts associated with the Camera API.
- Since I've used so many different code snippets from verified sources, I doubt it has to do with the js, html or css that I'm writing. I believe this to be a dependency issue, but I have no idea what it could be, and there's not much help out there for PhoneGap yet.

#### Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have any error logs when calling phonegap functions (like navigator.camera not found)? I see you use xcode, are you aware that you need to run `phonegap build ios` or `cordova prepare ios` in order to install completly the plugins? (be carefull running those commands will also overwrite the content of platforms/ios with what you have in the root www folder)